# "is_system_on" problem

Tags: control-panel, config

I am having a tough time getting "is_system_on" to work right in production. In the "General Config" page in the CP, neither the "yes" or "no" radio buttons are set. When I select one and click submit, they go blank again.

In 'config.php', I am seeing something like the following, with multiple "is_system_on" settings which looks suspicious. Any ideas?

```
$config['app_version'] = "253";
$config['install_lock'] = "";
$config['license_number'] = "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx";
$config['debug'] = "1";
$config['cp_url'] = "http://local.site.com/admin/index.php";
$config['doc_url'] = "http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/";
$config['is_system_on'] = "y";
$config['allow_extensions'] = 'y';
$config['site_label'] = 'My Site';
$config['cookie_prefix'] = '';
$config['is_system_on'] = "n";
$config['is_system_on'] = "n";
```

My config.php file is writeable (obviously, since the extra entries are showing up). I am using the focus labs config stuff, but removed the line hard-coding the is_system_on variable.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using FocusLab's master config, just double-check that is_system_on isn't being set as an environment config somewhere else (e.g. config/config.prod.php).

Answer (score 0):

The config var is being set 3 times. That said, based on that, the radio button should be showing as 'no' within the CP.

I would imagine in production (unless you're just about to put the site live and don't want anyone other than super admins accessing) you want to remove all but 1 instance of the variable, and set it to 'y'.

Comment: Yeah, I tried removing the redundant ones, and removing them all and starting from scratch... but it still results in the CP not showing either "yes" or "no" selected. The system always seems to be on, no matter what.

Comment: it could possibly be a bug, I noticed (particularly with 2.5.3) that there were times I would set config vars and they wouldn't be reflected within the CP. Are you able to upgrade to the latest version?

Comment: That's a good point. I hadn't considered that it could be someone else's fault :)

Comment: also curious to know how 3 of the same vars were written to the config also. Seems strange.